# Merge arrays to make a new array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

What is the way to merge two arrays (column-wise) into a new composite array in perl?

@array1

```
car
scooter
truck
```

@array2

```
four
two
six
```

I tried using following:

```
my @merged = (@array1, @array2); print @merged;
```

But it merges both arrays in one column as follows:

```
car
scooter
truck
four
two
six
```

But what I want is as follows:

```
@merged[0] @merged[1] 
car             four
scooter         two
truck           six
```

Comment: You want a 3x2 array ?  `my @merged = ( \@array1, \@array2 );`  But then you need to use 2 indexes to get the values out.  `my $scooter = $merged[0]->[1];`

Comment: multidimensional array should be possible

Comment: Have a read of `perldoc perldsc` : https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @merged;
for (0 .. $#array1) {
    push(@merged, ([$array1[$_],$array2[$_]]));
}
```

or

```
my @merged;
push @merged, map {[$array1[$_], $array2[$_]]} 0 .. $#array1;
```

Comment: That'll still produce one flat array like this - `car, four, scooter, two, truck, six`, while the OP seems to need it like this - `$merged[0] = \@array1, $merged[1] = \@array2;`.

Comment: Fixed(?) Obviously the arrays must be the same size too.

Comment: This is closer, but the matrix is inverted. In your code, `$merged[0]` will give *[car, four]*, while OP requests code for *car, scooter, truck*.

Answer (score 18):

In Perl, if you are storing the array(s) in list it will automatically flattened as a **single list**.

```
my @array = (@ar1,@ar2);
```

If you want to store as an array, you should make a reference to an array and store the reference to another array like

```
my @array = (\@ar1,\@ar2);
```

Now `@array` has reference of `@ar1` and `@ar2`.

Then use corresponding datatype to dereference the reference

In your case

```
print @{$array[0]};
```

Finally you can use the following for your case

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array1 = qw(car scooter truck);
my @array2 = qw(four five six);

my @merged = (\@array1,\@array2); #referencing the array1 and array2

foreach my $i (0..$#{$merged[0]}) 
{
    # getting the last index value using $#{$merged[0]}

    printf ("%-10s%-10s\n",$merged[0][$i],$merged[1][$i]);


}
```

Answer (score 4):

> But what I want is as follows:
>
> ```
> @merged[0] @merged[1] 
> car             four
> scooter         two
> truck           six
> ```

I see two ways to interpret this.

Either as mkHun did, as a list of two array references:

```
my @array1 = qw(a b c);
my @array2 = qw(x y z);
my @merged = (\@array1, \@array2); # (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

at which point you can do:

```
$merged[0]->[1] # 'b'
$merged[1]->[2] # 'z'
```

Or as a single list of interleaved elements:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);

my @array1 = qw(a b c);
my @array2 = qw(x y z);
my @merged = zip @array1, @array2; # ('a', 'x', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'z')
```

at which point you can do:

```
$merged[2] # 'b'
$merged[5] # 'z'
```

See [`List::MoreUtils::zip`](https://www.jobindex.dk/perldoc/List/MoreUtils#zip-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3) for this.

Answer (score 1):

This will do as requested:

```
my @merged;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#array1; ++$i)
{
    $merged[$i*2] = $array1[$i];
    $merged[$i*2+1] = $array2[$i];
}
```

Comment: That seems to interleave the two arrays, which is different than merging them, which is different than putting them into a two dimensional array (which OP seems to have wanted).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)) == (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the sample data, an associative array (hash) is probably a more appropriate data structure:

```
my %data;
@data{@array1} = @array2;

print $data{car}; # "four"
```